# Extract vnames from igraph object

Tags: r, igraph

Here is the example igraph object:

```
library(igraph)
#dummy data
d <- data.frame( x = LETTERS[1:5], y = LETTERS[5:1] )
links <- d
nodes <- as.character(d$x)

#graph object
net <- graph.data.frame(links, nodes, directed = FALSE)

str(net)
# IGRAPH UN-- 5 5 -- 
# + attr: name (v/c)
# + edges (vertex names):
#   [1] A--E B--D C--C B--D A--E
```

Tried below, didn't work, also tried some `igraph::get*` functions:

```
net$names
E(net)$vnames
E(net)$names
```

Closest to what I need is below (I could paste them, but wondering if I can get it from the object):

```
get.edgelist(net)
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,] "A"  "E" 
# [2,] "B"  "D" 
# [3,] "C"  "C" 
# [4,] "B"  "D" 
# [5,] "A"  "E"
```

I need a character vector as below:

```
"A|E" "B|D" "C|C" "B|D" "A|E"
```

Looks like it is already in the object, I can't seem to find the right function.

```
str(E(net))
# Class 'igraph.es'  atomic [1:5] 1 2 3 4 5
#   ..- attr(*, "vnames")= chr [1:5] "A|E" "B|D" "C|C" "B|D" ...
#   ..- attr(*, "env")=<weakref> 
#   ..- attr(*, "graph")= chr "8a71f114-20e8-11e6-bb83-f96f1023ec99"
```

Comment: `attr(E(net), "vnames")` ?

Comment: @Cath Thank you, feel free to post as an answer, but still this *looks* more complicated than it should be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `attr` function to retrieve the desired attribute:

```
attr(E(net), "vnames")
#[1] "A|E" "B|D" "C|C" "B|D" "A|E"
```

***NB***: as mentionned "elsewhere" by @Frank, if you look at `E` code, you'll see that the `vnames` attribute is built with paste: (`attr(res, "vnames") <- paste(el[, 1], el[, 2], sep = "|")` so you really can just paste `get.edgelist(net)` result...

Another option is to use `as_ids` to convert the edge sequence to a vector :

```
as_ids(E(net))
#[1] "A|E" "B|D" "C|C" "B|D" "A|E"
```

***NB***: `as_ids` calls `attr(., "vnames")` so it's not really a different option...

Comment: @zx8754 I added another option, maybe more like what you had in mind ?